# У переменной появился знак @, JsonDeserializeObject. Что это, почему, как исправить?

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio

```
public class MyTest
{
 public string arg1;
 public string type;
}  
string json1 = @"{""arg1"":""uuid"",""type"":""Full""};
var rt1= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <MyTest[]> (json1);
```

В отладчике:
[image: Отладчик]

У ключа type появился знак @. Откуда, что это?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что type - ключевое слово языка c#. Поэтому и ставится дополнительный знак @ чтобы не спутать его с ключевым словом.

Это не нужно исправлять, но в принципе просто переименуйте type во что-то другое, ну либо просто напишите с заглавной буквы:

```
public class MyTest
{
    public string Arg1 { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```